# Error with Bash script and ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, case

I have a bash script where I `ssh` to a remote host and then create a file depending on the operating system (`case` statement in bash). When I execute this code on OS X, I expect the value Darwin to be evaluated and the file eg2.txt to be created. However, for some reason the evaluation fails to choose Darwin and it selects `*` and then creates the file `none.txt`. Has anyone run into a similar issue? Can someone tell what is wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -l user $1 "cd Desktop; 
opname=`uname -s`;
echo \"first\" > first.txt
case \"$opname\" in 
    "Darwin") echo \"Darwin\" > eg2.txt ;;
    "Linux") sed -i \"/$2/d\" choice_list.txt ;;
    *) touch none.txt ;;
esac"
```

P.S. I am running this code primarily on a Mac.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `$opname` variable is being expanded (into the empty string) by the Bash instance that's running `ssh` (i.e., on the client-side), rather than being passed over SSH to be handled by the Bash instance on the server-side.

To fix this, you can either use single-quotes instead of double-quotes:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -l user $1 'cd Desktop; 
opname=`uname -s`;
echo "first" > first.txt
case "$opname" in 
    Darwin) echo "Darwin" > eg2.txt ;;
    Linux) sed -i "/$2/d" choice_list.txt ;;
    *) touch none.txt ;;
esac'
```

or else you can quote your `$` using `\`:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -l user $1 "cd Desktop; 
opname=`uname -s`;
echo \"first\" > first.txt
case \"\$opname\" in 
    "Darwin") echo \"Darwin\" > eg2.txt ;;
    "Linux") sed -i \"/\$2/d\" choice_list.txt ;;
    *) touch none.txt ;;
esac"
```